# Save pickle file with latest pandas version and load with pandas 0.23.4

Tags: pandas, version, pickle

i need to read pickle files saved with the latest version of pandas with pandas 0.23.4

With pandas 0.23.4
pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL: 4
With latest pandas it is
pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL: 5

I have tried to save using the latest version with the protocol option
data.to_pickle('data.pkl', compression='infer', protocol=4)

Yet i cant read it with pandas 0.23.4
Unfortunately i cant upgrade the pandas version on the reading part since "the Tool" only allowes that specific version.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Use a compatible version of pandas to read then save it on a different format that can be read from the older version. `feather` or `HDF5` format, both worked for me. `csv` would probably have worked, but i hate the possible type conversions.

- feather: Use `df.to_feather('df.feather')` to save and `df=pd.read_feather('df.feather')` to read.
- HDF5: Use `df.to_hdf('df.h5',key='df',mode='w')` to save and `df=pd.read_hdf('df.h5', key='df')` to read.